# How can we pair endpoints near to each other from list of points

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Source image 
[image]

```
I=imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDhl7.jpg');
```

Some preprocessing

```
nsc = bwareopen(~im2bw(I, .2),250);
i3=bwmorph(nsc,'thin');
```

we get thin image

[image]

```
 i4 = bwmorph(,'endpoints');
```

after morphing operation we get list of endpoints

[image]

Now i need to select those pairs of endpoints to close the door. as show in next image. [image]

So i can merge those images with the first one. to get this [image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem I'm seeing with your approach is that wall separating the kitchen and living room. It has an end point, but no door that attaches to it, unlike the other gaps in the walls where there are doors or windows attached to the endpoints, and those cases will be hard to separate.

So what exactly are you trying to do? Comparing your input and goal images, I suppose you want to color the separate rooms? Then I'd suggest using bwconncomp to get the connected regions in the image, delete the walls region, and iterate through the regions to color them.

Comment: While cleanup of doors, windows, and wc elements attached to wall from image, rooms get opened, so i am not able to get desired connected components as rooms. As i would like to have only walls with room, no window, door or other symbols.

Comment: i have also tried, bwdist, and waterfall to get rooms boundary but some time it create undesireable wall in the empty area.

Comment: I just saw that the door drawings show open doors, while the room colors should show rooms with their doors closed, so connected regions don't work. You could try fitting rectangles around, but that would only work on rectangular rooms.
But looking at your input image in Matlab, the doors and windows seem to have a different color than the drawings of WCs, etc and the walls. So you could extract the doors and windows by color, and pair them with the endpoints they touch to get the endpoint pairs.

Comment: Is the image linked in I=imread('http://i.stack.imgur.com/qDhl7.jpg'); a correct example? Because that imagesc(I) of that image shows the doors, windows and  text in a different color than the walls and appliances. If that's incorrect, you should rework your question and concretize it.

Comment: the colored image is desired output as allready mentioned in question

Comment: I am talking about the input. Reading that image into Matlab and displaying it using imagesc shows different colors for doors compared to walls and appliances for me. Is that correct behavior?

Comment: it might be just gray color, and it can be converted into bw using im2bw